# how to save data from ios app so it could be exported in an excel file

Tags: ios, excel, save

In my ios app, I have a form with radio buttons. Each time I fill the form, I would like to save the answers in the device (with an id for each user) so can later export all the choices in an excel file. How can I do that?

p.s I developed the app using MyEclipse.

Comment: CSV file should be the easiest way because Excel files are quite complex.

Comment: ok. how can I code that?

Comment: how can I do that using javascript